# Applications stops its work when TextView is empty. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, android

I have a `loginActivity` class. that does `email` and `password` validation and checks if a login field is empty.

the problem is that my application stops if the login fields are empty.

Here's my code :

**Validators :**

```java
private boolean validatePassword() {
    boolean password1 = password.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty();
    String password2 = password.getText().toString().trim();
    if (password1) {
        password.setError("Поле не должно быть пустым");
        return false;
    } else if (!PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(password2).matches()) {
        password.setError("Слабый пароль. ");
        return false;
    } else {
        password.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean validateEmail() {
    String email1 = email.getText().toString().trim();
    if (email1.isEmpty()) {
        email.setError("Поле не должно быть пустым");
        return false;
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email1).matches()) {
        email.setError("Введите правильный E-mail");
        return false;
    } else {
        email.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Registeration :**

```java
public void register(final String email, final String password) {
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (validateEmail() & validatePassword()) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty())
                Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Поля не должно быть пустыми", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

**Login :**

```java
public void logIn(final String email, final String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                if (validateEmail()) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startNewActivity();
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Проверьте введенные данные", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Changing activity :**

```java
private void startNewActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: Can you share log error? and you should validate email, password before create UserWithEmailAndPassword or signInWithEmailAndPassword

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to find an error in your code because you didn't post any logcat error message but I worked on something similar and it works perfectly for me, just change my fields like editTextPassword, editTextEmail and also in intents with your fields and you are good too go.

```
private void userLogin() {
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        editTextEmail.setError("Email is required");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        editTextEmail.setError("Please enter a valid email");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        editTextPassword.setError("Password is required");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.length() < 6) {
        editTextPassword.setError("Minimum lenght of password should be 6");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

you just have to call this function when the user clicks on login button.

```
Button loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            userLogin();

        }
    });
```